# Java ConcurrentSkipListMap entries locked on navigation

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrentskiplistmap

The below class appears to be stuck in the method lrPoints, when used with a client provided Map. The conclusion so far is that either lrPoint is running an infinite loop or there is a deadlock. I am unable to reproduce the bug but can assure by reading the logs that the method lrPoints is never exited.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.NavigableMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;

public final class TimeSeries {

    private final NavigableMap<LocalDateTime, Double> series = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();

    public TimeSeries(Map<LocalDateTime, Double> m) {
        series.putAll(m);
    }

    public Double get(LocalDateTime t){
        return series.get(t);
    }

    public Pair<Entry<LocalDateTime, Double>, Entry<LocalDateTime, Double>> lrPoints(LocalDateTime t) {
        if (series.isEmpty() || t.isBefore(series.firstKey()) || t.isAfter(series.lastKey()))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("t outside of time series bounds");
        Entry<LocalDateTime, Double> l = series.floorEntry(t);
        Entry<LocalDateTime, Double> r = series.ceilingEntry(t);
        return Pair.of(l,r);
    }
}
```

Adding to the problem, the "get" method returns ok. Is this map constructed correctly to prevent client locking? Is there any other reason this method could fail?

Edit. After adding more logging and changing to TreeMap. I see now the problem is the static constructor method Pair.of(.,.). Is there a reason such static initialiser could cause a deadlock?

Comment: Make a thread dump (`ctrl` + `break` if running inside a windows terminal, or `kill -3 process_id` if running inside  linux`), this will tell you if you have a deadlock, and tell you what threads are responsible for the deadlock

Comment: Thanks, i would like to try that however i only have access to logs...

Comment: [Try to reproduce your problem inside a smaller environment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), there are potential other issues that can cause your problem, like slow IO printing, slow database access, buffered printing to logs (this one can really make it *seem* like the problem is somewhere else), slow/stuck hard disk on accessing certain files (makes the VM behave unpredictable), try to make a program with a `public static void main()` that starts 2 threads that call `lrPoints` and `get` and at the same time, and see if it deadlocks.

Comment: Also, if you don't change `series` outside the constructor, you also don't need to make it a concurrent map, a simple TreeMap(or other sorted implementation) is safe for read-only access